# Suitable free email Service as the secondary account recommended by Bugzilla

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, email, gmail-labels, email-forwarding

Bugzilla sends the following to a new user (*after* receiving the primary address):

> We recommend using a secondary account or free web email service (such
>   as Gmail, Yahoo, Hotmail, or similar) to avoid receiving spam at your
>   primary email address.

Which publicly available service (paid or free) is suitable and reliably forwards Bugzilla messages to the primary address?

I've rejected Gmail because it often misIDs a Bugzilla message as spam, and having done so, omits to forward it to the primary address.

I've rejected Fastmail because it has a known issue wherein it tampers with headers breaking the ARC signature and causing forwarded email to be properly rejected by Gmail.

Answer (score 1):

> I've rejected Gmail because it often misIDs Bugzilla as spam...

**Actually, you CAN use Gmail**.

Just create a filter for it:

1. `Settings`
2. `Filters and blocked addresses`
3. At the bottom of your page click on `Create a new filter`
4. In the `From` field type `@bugzilla.org`
5. In the next screen choose: `Forward it to:`, `Never send to Spam`

***Pro Tip:***
*You can even create a new label like `Bugzilla` and have it applied as well. You could also apply the filter to your -if any- older emails.*

[image]